# SQS traffic balancing

Tags: amazon-sqs, continuous-deployment

I have an app, that is reading events from Amazon SQS. The problem, I have is that when I deploy a newer application version, it connects to same queue, so there are two stacks - old and new one consuming messages.

I would like to keep old stack consuming say 95% of messages and new only 5% so I can do a live test. When I am confident, new version is fine, I shut down old stack and make new one consume 100% of events.

The only solution, I see right now is to implement some feature on application side, for example some REST endpoint, to control how many SQS messages it should try to read.
However, may be there are some other solutions/tools for this problem. (in fact, there are several applications, so if I can solve this issue without touching all of them, it would be great)

In general how do you deal with new version deployments and reading from SQS?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say there are two application stacks: S1, which needs to process 90% of the messages, and S2 10%.

This is what they can do:

- They'll have two configurations: `n_messages_to_get` and `n_messages_to_process`. For S1, the values will be 10 and 9 respectively. For S2, 10 and 1 respectively.
- Each will fetch `n_messages_to_get` from SQS, but only process `n_messages_to_process` out of them.

You can also think of having this configuration in a database like DynamoDB, so that you don't have to deploy your code in case you need to dial up or down.

Assumptions made:

- Both S1 and S2 take approximately same time to process a message.
- You can tolerate some deviation in the number of messages processed by both. For e.g., you'll be OK if S1 processes 87% of the messages and S2 13%.

Comment: marking this as correct answer since that seem to be the only viable solution. At the end I end up with implementing this feature with configuration values on app side, as @ketan described